# Random Text Sent to UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I'm trying to create an array that holds x amount of literal strings that will randomly send one to a UILabel after you hit a UIButton.

How should I structure the .h and .m files to do this? Also, what is the best way to generate the random number I need?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: he's obviously asking how to do the above. Common sense.

Answer (score 1):

You would get a random integer for the index, and then just pass the object you get to the UILabel's text property, eg:

```
//assuming you already have an NSArray of strings
myLabel.text = [arrayOfString objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [arrayOfString count]];
```

You'd put the above code in the method that the button calls when it's pressed.

EDIT: [As requested here's a simple Xcode project](http://www.mediafire.com/?t4idbrxm5s1mi2g).

(NOTE: As it's random there's a chance that you'll get the same text so it may appear that the text doesn't change, it does but it changes to the same text as before which you don't see)

Comment: Thank you both, I have a fairly good idea of the logic, but I'm having trouble getting the right syntax into the .h, .m, and placing the IB Elements.

If it's not too much, could someone post a very simple/generic Xcode project of this, so that I can dissect it?

Thank you oh so very much.

Very curious/ambitious noob.

Comment: @hey_suburbia, I've uploaded a simple Xcode I made to show the connections, I've edited my answer to include the link to it.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan.  In my early stages of objective-c and Xcode, having my thoughts put into a working file for me to study are priceless learning tools, I greatly appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application 
{   
    //Create window
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    sampleArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"iPhone", @"iPod", @"iMac", @"Newton",@"iPad",@"Lisa",@"Mac mini",@"Delta" ,nil] retain];
    randButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
    [randButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 30.0f, 60.0f, 40.0f)];
    [randButton setTitle:@"Random" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [randButton addTarget:self action:@selector(randNumberGenerate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_window addSubview:randButton];    
}


- (void) randNumberGenerate
{
    NSString* string = [sampleArray objectAtIndex:(arc4random()%[sampleArray count])];
    UILabel* displayRandNum = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0f, 30.0f, 80.0f, 30.0f)];
    displayRandNum.text = string;
    [_window addSubview:displayRandNum];
    [displayRandNum release];
}
```

Comment: Thank you both, I have a fairly good idea of the logic, but I'm having trouble getting the right syntax into the .h, .m, and placing the IB Elements.

If it's not too much, could someone post a very simple/generic Xcode project of this, so that I can dissect it?

Thank you oh so very much.

Very curious/ambitious noob.

Comment: @hey_suburbia You can pick up the code from here: http://www.mediafire.com/?pcbe9d7f6jqps5n

Comment: Thank you, MacDev! It means so much to have guidance early on in my studies.  Cheers!