# move UILabel randomly between 4 or 5 x/y coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, random

Im trying to figure out a way to move a UILabel to different pre determined points on the screen at random (that is, to choose from a list of pre determined points randomly and move there).

My initial thoughts is to write a  method that will choose randomly from an array but would I need two seperate arrays for the x and the Y? Any suggestions or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the code from this question (getting a random object from an array)
[Random Text Sent to UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889551/random-text-sent-to-uilabel/4889984#4889984)

You could store the CGPoint in an NSValue, and then in the array (as you can't put a CGPoint directly in an NSArray as it's not an object) Eg:

```
NSArray *arrayOfPoints = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point1],
                          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(12, 14)],
                          nil];
```

(The example code just above stores just 2 points, you can have as many as you like, and the first value is if the CGPoint already exists/created dynamically and the second value is if you want to make the point on the spot)

Bringing the code across from the question I linked to, and adapted it to your question:

```
CGPoint randomPoint = [arrayOfPoints objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [arrayOfPoints count]];

myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(randomPoint.x, randomPoint.y, myLabel.frame.size.width, myLabel.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Let me just clarify what i'm trying to do to make sure your solution will work. So i have 4 points on the screen lets say 32/45, 123/56, 56/78 and 89/75 (or whatever). Now when I call the method i need my label to move to one of those four points. It doesnt matter which one it just has to be one of the four.